# How can I make a counter in PHP that counts up to 10 (including "first decimal-place" numbers)?

Tags: php, for-loop, decimal, counter

I'm trying to make a PHP counter and this is what I have:

```
<?PHP
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    print "$i";
    }
?>
```

It's quite a simple counter but I was wondering if it could count all the decimal numbers (only one decimal place) as well, is there any way I could do that?

This is what I would like:

```
0.1,
0.2,
0.3,
...
9.8,
9.9,
10.0.
```

Comment: There are an infinite number of decimal fractions between each integer (whole number). You would have to decide what precision you want first; i.e. how many decimal places.

Comment: You realize that there is an infinite number of decimal numbers between 0 and 10?

Comment: Loop from 1 to 100, and print them all out divided by 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to count from 1 to 10, including ALL decimals. There would be infinitely many of them.

However, you could count in tenths:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i+=0.1) {
print "$i\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: A heads up: Neither this solution nor the counter in your original question will actually include "10.0" in the output, as you stated is your desire.  You would have to use "$i <= 10" as the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide on a precision.  Let's say you want a decimal precision of 2 decimal places for this exercise (but this could obviously be changed in code).  My suggestion would be to simply implement an integer counter between 0 and 1000 and then divide counter value by 100 to get decimal values.

```
$decimal_precision = 2;
$counter_limit = 10;
$counter_ratio = (int)pow(10, $decimal_precision);
$integer_limit = $counter_limit * $counter_ratio;


for($i = 1; $i <= $integer_limit; $i++) {
    echo (float) $i / $counter_ratio;
}
```